# Forcing HorizontalScrollView to take up full width and center children

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a horizontal scrollview to take up the full width of the screen and have its child view centered.  So far, I'm ending up with it just wrapping the children and everything is left aligned.  My view looks like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#CD000000"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Inside that we inflate something that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/mode_panzoom"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingBottom="5dip"
      android:paddingLeft="5dip"
      android:paddingRight="5dip"
      android:minWidth="75dip"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pan"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mode_panzoom"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode_annotate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:minWidth="75dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_annotate"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mode_panzoom"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mode_measure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:minWidth="75dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_measure"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mode_panzoom"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fillviewport seems to do nothing, and applying gravities seeems to have no effect, probably because its wrapping content even though I set fill_parent as the width.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of how it looks in hierachyviewer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out my problem, and it ended up being nothing related to the xml.  It was the fact that I was inflating the contents of the HorizontalScrollView.  After that, if you want your parent to fill_parent correctly you need to force it to layout again via request_layout.  Otherwise it won't get the correct size.